# crystal report 2008. use custom functions or formulas in query

Tags: function, group-by, crystal-reports

I need to write a query to calculate sum of field values matching a given condition. So, I wrote this custom report function

```sql
Function get_order_amount (ord_amount as number, inv_date as date, month as string, year as string)
    -- ...
    if inv_date(yyyymm) <= tonumber(year + month) then
        return ord_amount
    else
        return 0
    end if
End Function
```

now, I wish to use my function in the command query to filter data to sum. ie:
(q_sum)

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDER_DATE) AS "YEAR", 
    SUM(GET_ORDER_AMOUNT(AMOUNT,INVOICE_DATE,{?P_MONTH},{?P_YEAR}))
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDER_DATE)
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You are trying to mix sql query with crystal reports function....i am not sure how it works but instead of using in query... dont complicate query.. use simple select statement and use custom function in crystal report formulas

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can mix custom functions with SQL queries.

Instead you can use CASE statements directly in the SQL.

The case statement would look something like this

```
Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDER_DATE) as YEAR
              , SUM(CASE
              WHEN INV_DATE <= **SOMEDATE** THEN
                        ORD_AMOUNT
              ELSE
                        0
              END) as Custom_Total
    FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDER_DATE)
```